# Passing IConfiguration to constructor using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, .net-5

I'm trying to use `C#` `Reflection` to create an instance, my constructor is receiving two parameters:

- `ILogger`
- `IConfiguration`

I created the `ILogger` and passed it to the constructor it's working fine, but the `IConfiguration` is not working because the object of `IConfiguration` is returning `ConfigurationRoot` object

`class` code:

```
public class Weekly 
    {
        public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
        private readonly ILogger<Weekly> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public Weekly(ILogger<Weekly> ilogger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = ilogger;
            _configuration = configuration;
            SessionId = Guid.NewGuid();
            Console.WriteLine("Weekly inestance created with id: " + SessionId.ToString());
            _logger.LogInformation("Weekly inestance created with id: " + SessionId.ToString());
        }
        public void Report()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Weekly report called");
            _logger.LogInformation("Weekly report called");
        }
    }
```

creating `object` :

```
    foreach (ConstructorInfo constructor in constructors)
                {
                    ParameterInfo[] parameters = constructor.GetParameters();
                    if (parameters.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        object[] objs = new object[parameters.Count()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            if (typeof(ILogger).IsAssignableFrom(parameters[i].ParameterType))
                            {
                                objs[i] = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ILogger<dynamic>)) as ILogger<dynamic>;
                            }
                            else if (typeof(IConfiguration).IsAssignableFrom(parameters[i].ParameterType))
                            {
                         //here i'm adding IConfiguration
                                objs[i] = _serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
                            }
                        }
                        instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, objs);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    }
                }
```

**Edit:**
I'm getting the error
`System.AggregateException`: *'One or more errors occurred. (Constructor on type 'WeeklyReport.Weekly' not found.)'*

Comment: AFAIK there is no error. The class `ConfigurationRoot` implements `IConfiguration`.

Comment: why I'm getting System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Constructor on type 'WeeklyReport.Weekly' not found.)'

Comment: In your code you iterate through the constructors. Then you take the first with *any* count of parameter (maybe 1,2,3, etc.). Next you know how to create two kinds of argument types and provide these. What if your choosen ctor has more parameters or other types?

Comment: Also your first parameter is of type `ILogger<dynamic>` which is not `ILogger<Weekly>`. That doesn't match.

Comment: I'm adding more handlers to other parameters types it's just not completed yet.

Comment: @Oliver yes you are right the real problem is in `ILogger<dynamic>`, it has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

the problem was in `ILogger<Weekly>` in `Weekly` class, I was trying to pass `ILogger<dynamic>` to `ILogger<Weekly>`

I just made a change in Weekly class :

```
public class Weekly 
    {
        public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
        private readonly ILogger<dynamic> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public Weekly(ILogger<dynamic> ilogger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = ilogger;
            _configuration = configuration;
            SessionId = Guid.NewGuid();
            Console.WriteLine("Weekly inestance created with id: " + SessionId.ToString());
            _logger.LogInformation("Weekly inestance created with id: " + SessionId.ToString());
        }
        public void Report()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Weekly report called");
            _logger.LogInformation("Weekly report called");
        }
    }
```

and finally, it's working fine.